# How do I join 3 tables together with MySQL... and omit the columns from the second "Middle" table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have 3 tables : 
Users, which contains relevant user data

ComputerUsers, which ties together Users with information from a fourth (and for my purposes here irrelevant) table, Computers.

And finally, Software, which contains a list of software present on various computers.

The only thing tying a user together with a piece of software is

```
Users.User_ID <-> ComputerUsers.User_ID/ComputerUsers.Computer_ID<->Software.Computer_ID
```

I know that I can use

```
SELECT * FROM Users INNER JOIN ComputerUsers ON Users.User_ID = ComputerUsers.User_ID INNER JOIN Software ON ComputerUsers.Computer_ID = Software.Computer_ID
```

to tie together the user with all of their software, especially if I filter it like

```
Where Users.User_ID = 'Some_Value'
```

My gripe is that when I run this SQL, I get a result set that contains : 
All of the columns from the Users table, both columns from the Computer_Users table, and all columns from the software table.

I'm sure there's a better way to do this but I'm a rookie with MySQL, SQL, and database stuff in general.

How would I go about accomplishing joining together the Users table with the Software table while omitting the columns from the Computer_Users table?

Comment: List the columns explicitly in the `select` statement.  That does what you want.  Plus, it's a good idea.

Comment: that was frighteningly fast...

Also, if you want to put that in answer form I'll mark it.

Comment: We aim to please :P (and Gordon is gunning for 1st place in points acquired this year)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this to get columns from just two tables:

```
SELECT u.*, s.*
FROM Users u INNER JOIN
     ComputerUsers cu
     ON u.User_ID = cu.User_ID INNER JOIN
     Software s
     ON cu.Computer_ID = s.Computer_ID;
```

A cleverer way is to use the `using` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users u INNER JOIN
     ComputerUsers cu
     USING (User_ID) INNER JOIN
     Software s
     USING (Computer_ID);
```

Columns used for the `join` conditions do not get repeated when you use `USING`.

Comment: #2, me gusta. I guess the next question I'll have to ask is how do I use LINQ to Data Set to make this work in .Net with 3 tables...

Answer (score 1):

You need to list the columns you want in the SELECT portion of the query, rather than using *. You can do this by table:

```
SELECT Users.*, Software.*
FROM ...
```

Or by column:

```
SELECT Users.UserName, Users.Login, Software.Title, Software.Version ...
FROM ...
```